# Not able to use different model for Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am using retrofit and when I use the callback method, retrofit forces me to use the same model, but my response have different models.

```
WebserviceHelper.getInstancePost().getbook(10).enqueue(new Callback< serverModel>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<serverModel> call, Response<serverModel> response) {

                data = (List<advertise_book>) response.body().getResult();
                adapter = new advertise_adapter(getActivity(), data);
                list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
                Log.w("response", response.message());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<serverModel> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.w("response", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

Everything is fine when I use the above code, but when I use the code below in a different activity, I get the error that use the **serverModel** instead of the **servermodel_note**

```
WebserviceHelper.getInstancePost().getnote(10).enqueue(new Callback<servermodel_note>() {

           @Override
           public void onResponse(Call<servermodel_note> call, Response<servermodel_note> response) {
               data = (List<advertise_note>) response.body().getResult();
               adapter = new note_adapter(getActivity(), data);
               list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
               list.setAdapter(adapter);
               Log.w("response", response.message());
           }
           @Override
           public void onFailure(Call<servermodel_note> call, Throwable t) {

           }
       });
```

and this is my error

> error: incompatible types: <anonymous Callback<servermodel_note>>
> cannot be converted to Callback < serverModel>

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For retrofit calls, the generic for the `Call` and `Response` parameter in the `onResponse` callback are defined by the return type of the method.

For example, the method below will require that the `Call<User>` and `Response<User>` parameters are passed into the `onResponse` callback for this call:

```
@POST("users/new")
Call<User> createUser(@Body User user);
```

A different response requires a different call definition. Create an additionall call definition in your retrofit class that returns a `Call<servermodel_note>`.